# Google Maps API V2 not showing

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

I am developing an android app through 2 different computers, desktop when I'm home and laptop when I'm on the road. I'm pretty sure the app project folder is completely the same, and so are the library projects (Google Play Service). The only difference is API Key, I had to make 2 different key on Google Developer Console. Weird thing is, today I just realized my app I installed from laptop is not showing the map. Here's what I found from LogCat:

```
10-08 08:49:23.491: W/ResourcesManager(25061): Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
10-08 08:49:23.491: W/ResourcesManager(25061): Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
10-08 08:49:23.491: W/asset(25061): Asset path /system/framework/com.google.android.ble.jar is neither a directory nor file (type=1).
10-08 08:49:23.491: W/ResourcesManager(25061): Asset path '/system/framework/com.google.android.ble.jar' does not exist or contains no resources.
10-08 08:49:23.505: I/Google Maps Android API(25061): Google Play services client version: 5089000
10-08 08:49:23.517: I/Google Maps Android API(25061): Google Play services package version: 6111038
10-08 08:49:23.867: D/REQUEST(25061): Using server: https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap/api
10-08 08:49:23.887: D/REQUEST(25061): Add Data Request: 75
10-08 08:49:23.894: D/REQUEST(25061): Add Data Request: 75
10-08 08:49:24.074: D/USER_EVENTS(25061): Event: type=78, status: MD, data: T
10-08 08:49:24.202: D/USER_EVENTS(25061): Event: type=113, status: mc, data: 
10-08 08:49:24.205: D/REQUEST(25061): Add Data Request: 147
10-08 08:49:24.280: I/Choreographer(25061): Skipped 54 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-08 08:49:24.604: D/USER_EVENTS(25061): Event: type=58, status: gl, data: |r=8|g=8|b=8|a=0|d=24|s=8|v=Qualcomm|i=OpenGL ES-CM 1.1|c=Adreno (TM) 330|e=t|
```

I'm guessing it's my Google Play Service library in laptop that is defect, but I tried replacing it with a newer version. I also have tried renewing my API Key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use same keystore file while building apk. No need to use two different API keys, if ur using same keystore.

Package version : Is what you add to your project. (Google play service Lib)
client version : Is the actual version of the google play services installed in your phone.

Google play services in your two different laptops are not same.

Install the latest Google Play Services from the Android SDK manager

Comment: isn't keystore bounded to Java installed in each computer?

Comment: Keystores are simply files with in a format used by java for keystores. They do not contain any information which ties them to a particular system. They can be freely copied between systems and directories as required.

Comment: @Anggrian did you solve installing the latest google play services? because I don't get why if the package version is already newest respect to the client one, you need to update the package one.

Comment: @DQuaglio I was having this problem in Eclipse with different google play services library in different computers. The issue seems to be gone after I moved to Android Studio. I believe the google play service is already integrated there, I just have to enable it in manifest. I hope it helps you.